# Add Classes or ID to an Adobe Fireworks Interactive Map

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, adobe-illustrator, fireworks

I am creating an interactive country map with Adobe Fireworks. My question is that is there any way I can add a class or id to a specific section?

I see an option to add links, alt and target attributes, but no such way to add classes or ID. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself guys. [I did this to get what I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PewUw.png)
basically, all I had to do was add javascript:doSomething(); to the link box